# Jquery Cycle timing variation with respect to amount of data in table

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, cycle

Consider a table like

```
<div class='Textslideshow'>
<table width='600px' style='padding-left:0%;' border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td width='100%' align='center' valign='middle' style="font-family: Arial">Header1</td>
        <tr>
            <td width='100%' align='center' valign='middle' style="font-family:Arial">
                <table border='1' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='7'>
                    <tr>
                        <td width='50%' align='center'>Time1</td>
                        <td width='50%' align='center'>Label1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width='50%' align='center'>Time2</td>
                        <td width='50%' align='center'>Label2</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width='600px' style='padding-left:0%;' border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td width='100%' align='center' valign='middle' style="font-family: Arial">Header2</td>
            <tr>
                <td width='100%' align='center' valign='middle' style="font-family:Arial">
                    <table border='1' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='7'>
                        <tr>
                            <td width='50%' align='center'>Time1</td>
                            <td width='50%' align='center'>Label1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width='50%' align='center'>Time2</td>
                            <td width='50%' align='center'>Label2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Under this div, having several tables like this, I cycle through each table by using Jquery cycle at a certain speed of 5 sec. Now, the html page can show only 10 entries of Time and Label. If there are more than 10 entries, I need to split the time say 2.5 sec for 1-10 and 10+ in other 2.5 sec. And the rest of the tables to be shown normally for 5 sec. The corresponding Jquery is where textspeed is 5000.

```
$(window).load(function () {

    $('.Textslideshow').cycle({
        fx: textTransitionEffect,
        speed: textSpeed,
        timeout: textTimeout
    });
});
```

This code works for tables having entries from 1-10 (Time & Label). If you have more entries then the entries get appended to the table. But I require to split up the table(with entries more than 10) and show it 2.5 sec each. jsFiddle link [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XXgc7/16/)

Any suggestions for this.

Comment: StackOverflow is intended to help you with code you have written, not to write code for you. If you can show us the code you have written I'm sure someone can help you improve it.

Comment: @Rory I have added everything that i have done so far. I dont expect any code. If possible share your ideas how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I made this work by using the following code

```
$('#MovieDisplayTiming').append(opthtml);
                    $('#MovieDisplayTiming div').css('width', $('#MovieDisplayTiming').width());
                    $('#MovieDisplayTiming').cycle({
                        fx: 'fade',
                        after: function () { $('.fillingfast').blink(1000); },
                        speed: 2000,
                        timeout: 8000,
                        before: function (curElement, nextElement, options, forwardFlag) {
                            if ($('.DisplayIndividualTiming').length !== 0) {
                                $('.DisplayIndividualTiming').cycle({
                                    fx: 'scrollUp',
                                    speed: 'slow',
                                    timeout: 4000,
                                    autostop: true
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
```